# Update Full Name in Forms Based Authentication

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, forms-authentication

I use SharePoint 2013 with Forms Based Authentication. I can update email, but I cannot update Full name from C#, how can I do that?

(Note: It is not the User Name / Login name i will change, but the Full name).

I kan change the e-mail (and username) like this.

```
    public void ChangeEmail(string loginName,string email)
    {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(_site.ID))
            {
                site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                site.RootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                string emailUser = Utils.BaseMembershipProvider(site).GetUserNameByEmail(email);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailUser) && emailUser != loginName)
                {
                    throw new EmailAddressExists();
                }
                MembershipUser user = Utils.BaseMembershipProvider(site).GetUser(loginName, false);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    user.Email = email;
                    user.UserName = "I need to change the Full Name, not the username";
                    Utils.BaseMembershipProvider(site).UpdateUser(user);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a 'full name' field in your database? I checked ours and can't find one. You might set up another table for your specific fields?

Comment: Yes I am. I have an other guy to look at it. Hope he can solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add additional properties to the user database. All you can do is add the FBA user into SharePoint, and while adding it provide the additional parameter like full name. This data will be saved in SharePoint.

For more details refer the below code from SharePoint FBA Pack github page.
https://github.com/Visigo/SharePointFBAPack/blob/master/Visigo.Sharepoint.FormsBasedAuthentication/Visigo.Sharepoint.FormsBasedAuthentication/Layouts/FBA/MANAGEMENT/UserNew.aspx.cs#L100